# Using Master Config

Tags: config, focus-lab-master-config

I am using this Master Config, http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-server-setup-for-ee-2

Problem is my site now shows a server error.

Here is a pastie of my master config file.

http://pastebin.com/G2PvFFck

ERROR

```
Warning:
require(/Applications/MAMP/Development/ExpressionEngine/pixelsandcode/../config/‌​config.master.php):
failed to open stream:
No such file or directory in 
/Applications/MAMP/Development/ExpressionEngine/pixelsandcode/pixels/expressione‌​ngine/config/config.php
on line 38

Fatal error:
require():
Failed opening required '/Applications/MAMP/Development/ExpressionEngine/pixelsandcode/../config/config.‌​master.php'
(include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php') in
/Applications/MAMP/Development/ExpressionEngine/pixelsandcode/pixels/expressione‌​ngine/config/config.php
on line 38
```

Comment: Whats the server error? anything in logs? also in index.php set debug to "1" to show errors

Comment: Also this is my config.php file which sits in:

/pixels/expressionengine/config/

http://pastebin.com/Us212bzE

Comment: It just says Server Error, in Chrome.

Apache logs just say:

[Wed Jul 17 14:41:39 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/Development/ExpressionEngine/pixelsandcode/favicon.ico

In Firefox I just get a white screen.

Comment: Okay with the  white screen you need to edit the index.php in the webroot and set debug= "1". Expression engine hides errors by default and you need to enable debugging. Once you do that post your errors

Comment: Warning: require(/Applications/MAMP/Development/ExpressionEngine/pixelsandcode/../config/config.master.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/Development/ExpressionEngine/pixelsandcode/pixels/expressionengine/config/config.php on line 38


Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Applications/MAMP/Development/ExpressionEngine/pixelsandcode/../config/config.master.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/Development/ExpressionEngine/pixelsandcode/pixels/expressionengine/config/config.php on line 38

Comment: Ok, so I know its a pathing issue, but I just can't figure that out.

Comment: config.master.php  is has a reference to "require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../config/config.' . ENV . '.php';"  If you have not moved your system folder this is incorrect and should be "require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config/config.' . ENV . '.php';"

Comment: Ok, now I'm a little confused.  Here is my config.master.php again.

http://pastebin.com/HpmeYUKj

My folder structure is:

http://cl.ly/QIio

Comment: ok  look at this -> https://gist.github.com/tsmith86/6020920

Comment: ok, but now I am getting this error:

Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

Comment: did you change anything else in index.php ?  its just set to the wrong directory.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/NickToye/6021149

If I change my system folder to that name I get the following error (added in that gist comments)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/NickToye/6021149#comment-865409  Basically its just making sure your paths are correct.

Comment: Sorry I commented on the gist.

Answer (score 1):

If you see this or a similar error with the double-period in the path -- `/../config/config.master.php` -- you just need to modify the following in config.master.php

REPLACE ANY OCCURRENCE OF THIS

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../config/config.' . ENV . '.php';
```

WITH THIS

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config/config.' . ENV . '.php';
```